# Issue with loadNamedStyle in QGIS 3.0.1

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3

I have saved a style as qml file. I try to set the style for a raster layer in python directly. For this, I use function "loadNamedStyle". After the call, the color themes are updated in my model but the description text under the raster layer is still not updated. My question, how can I refresh the information?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This solution helped me. My problem is solved.

```
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology( iface.activeLayer().id() )
```